# Populate an array element with 2 datarows at a time

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

i want to populate an array element with 2 datarows at a time.
i am using javascript pausescroller and on every single array element i want to show 2 Rows in the scroller.

sample code is

```
Datatable tblNews;

    for(int i = 0; i < tblNew.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
       array[i] = tblNews.Rows[i][""].ToString() + "" + tblNews.Rows[i + 1][""].ToString(); 
    }
```

but problem is i am getting error that no row found at position 1;
Any solution guys

Comment: in your loop you'll probably want i+=2 instead of i++, or else you're going to overwrite yourself

Comment: You are iterating the rows *i* and *i + 1* at the same time. It will always fail because an array is zero-based and once you get to the `Rows.Count` element (which is really at index `Rows.Count - 1`) you are accessing the last one, and one past, causing an invalid access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yah, quite simply, when you're getting to the end of your `tblNew.Rows.Count` you're adding another one and that doesn't exist in your rows...

so a quick and dirty fix...

```
    for(int i = 0; i < tblNew.Rows.Count-1; i++)
    {
       // do a quick check to make sure there is a row there to get data from
       string addMe = i + 1 <= tblNews.Rows.Count-1 ? tblNews.Rows[i+1][""].ToString() : ""; 
       array[i] = tblNews.Rows[i][""].ToString() + "" + addMe; 
    }
```